# agent key RSA SHA256:... returned incorrect signature type

Tags: ssh, digital-signature, rsync, msys2

I am doing `rsync`, and I get the message

```
agent key RSA SHA256:... returned incorrect signature type
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223333/agent-key-rsa-sha256-returned-incorrect-signature-type) it is mentioned that "This message isn't intrinsically fatal, although the remote side may choose to reject your connection if it doesn't support SHA-1 signatures."
This is exactly what I see: `rsync` gives me the expected results (I guess it is irrelevant that `rsync` is involved).
This is an explanation of the reasons behind the warning, but I found no way of fixing it.

I am using Msys2 under Win 10.

**Is there any way to fix it?**

Note that I have tried the following ssh connections among 3 computers:

```
   Comp A                         Comp B                    Comp C
Win 10, Msys2   ----------->   Ubuntu 18.04   ----------->   RHEL6
     |             Warning                     No warning      ^
     |                                                         |
     |---------------------------------------------------------|
                             No warning
```

On the client side I am using `pageant.exe` ver 0.66 and [`ssh-pageant 1.4`](https://github.com/cuviper/ssh-pageant) in Msys2 ("An SSH authentication agent for Cygwin/MSYS that links OpenSSH to PuTTY's Pageant.").

Comment: What tool are you using as your SSH agent?  That's the program that's broken, and you'd need to update it to avoid the warning.

Comment: @bk2204 - Would this be the agent on the server or client side?
See edited OP.

Comment: That would be the agent you're using on the client side (comp A), which is the one that produces the signature.  RHEL 6 is too old to support SHA-2 signatures, so it doesn't trigger the warning.

Comment: @bk2204 - Please see edited OP. Would you think it is pageant or ssh-pageant?
I am not certain, but I think I had ssh'd before between the same systems without this warning.
I will try getting another server with a "modern" OS to connect to and check.

Comment: I know nothing about Windows and the tooling.  If you're using pageant, you require version 0.71 or later.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Your issue here, and on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1542487/529800), appears to arise from using an insecure SHA1 based key, as no SSH server should currently support SHA1 because it's a security risk.  A general FYI, OpenSSH has been [ported](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki) to Windows by Microsoft.

Comment: @JW0914 - I know, that is why I changed. And I know that OpenSSH is in Win, I have setup an OpenSSH server in another PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by bk2204, there is support for SHA-256/512 RSA signatures [starting from pageant 0.71](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/pageant-rsa-sha2.html).

So I updated to putty 0.73 and the warning is gone.

Comment: PuTTY has contained support for SHA256 for years... hardware acceleration for SHA256 was added in v0.71, not support for SHA256 in general.  PuTTY's supported SHA256 for [at least](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html) 13 years, if not longer (DH SHA256 support added 2007-01-24 in v0.59).