# agent key RSA SHA256 returned incorrect signature type

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, ssh-keygen

i'm using vscode development container with docker but i have a problem when sharing git with container. i've setup git, ssh-add, ssh-agent as follows in [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container) and everything work as well. But when i try to do git pull in container terminal it gives me error `agent key RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx returned incorrect signature type`, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57237705/6309).

Try a regenerate, for testing, a new set of keys, making sure [you do not use pageant/putty](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pageant), but [only openssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35111050/6309).
And don't protect it with a passphrase (again, for testing), in order to avoid the ssh-agent step.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM
```

Comment: You could also use an Ed25519 key instead, which won't have this problem and is considered more secure anyway.

Comment: i've regenerate my ssh keys with this and restart the ssh-agent service, it's working well now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
find .git/objects/ -size 0 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

this fixed it for me, I had corrupt and empty objects