# agent key RSA SHA256: returned incorrect signature type

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh, secure-crt

I always use `SecureCRT` to connecting `WSL` (version 1, Ubuntu image).

But on the newer `Ubuntu image (20.04.1 LTS)`, I got the below notice every time when running `ssh` command.

```
agent key RSA SHA256:U9tL1mjyeoT6PRQaEZHyBH7ZY+PZ6T0I5Z5IZi+qGDs returned incorrect signature type
```

It looks terrible. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136363/), but the answer doesn't fit my situation.

Because what I using to load keys is SecureCRT, not ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

I Generated a new public/private key pair by the below command and replaced my old one. Not any notice now.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

See also [Upgrade Your SSH Key to Ed25519](https://medium.com/risan/upgrade-your-ssh-key-to-ed25519-c6e8d60d3c54)