# Receiving ssh-key warning inside a Visual-Studio-Code dev-container when pulling/pushing to private Github repo

Tags: windows, git, docker, visual-studio-code, ssh-keys

I have been developing inside a container with visual-studio-code on Windows 10 with the [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) plugin. I used [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container) to setup my ssh-agent and add my git credentials from windows 10 to the environment inside the container. But when I try to push or pull from a private repo github in that environment I receive the following error.

`agent key RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+64 returned incorrect signature type`

This does not seem to affect my ability to access my private repo on github, but the warning still seems like something I should be taking seriously. I am still able to use git on windows 10 without getting any errors. This only occurs if I use visual studio's remote-containers plugin with my Dockerfile, otherwise I'm not able to access the private repo at all due to my git credentials not being added to the container.

I've looked at some other SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223333/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136363/) and tried the regenerating my ssh-key using openssh on the windows side which did not seem to fix the problem. I've been using node:12.18-alpine3.12 as my base image and I've been installing openssh in my Dockerfile using

`apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache openssh`

so I'm assuming openssh should be a recent enough version.
I think this might be a plugin issue with vscode? I don't really know.